# Is $N \trianglelefteq G$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, direct-sum, direct-product

#### Assumption throughout the post:

Suppose that $G = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$ and $N = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$.

#### Question #1:

> Is the following attempt correct?

#### My attempt:

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group, then $G$ is an abelian group. Therefore, every subgroup of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Hence, $N \le G$, implies $N \trianglelefteq G$.

#### Question #2:

> Is $N = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z} := \{(0, a_1, a_2, \dots , a_k, 0, 0, \dots) \, \mid \, (\forall i \in \mathbb{N})([1 \le k \le i] \Rightarrow [a_k \ne 0])\, \wedge \, (\forall k > i)(a_k = 0)\}$, where $a_j = f(j)$, for some $f \in \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$?

Here, $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$ is the infinite direct product of groups.

Comment: No. Just remove the part that $a_k\ne 0$ for $1\le k\le i$. You only want that $a_0=0$ and only finitely many $a_k$ are non-zero.

Comment: $N$ isn't even a subset of $G$, much less a subgroup.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki, so, $(0, 0, 1, 2,-5, 6, 0, \dots) \in N$?

Comment: $(0, 0, 1, 2, -5, 6, \dots)$ have continued zeroes after $6$, btw.

Comment: Yes. By the way, the title of your post has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, why is not $N \subseteq G$?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki does it require that in $G$, $a_0 \ne 0$?

Comment: The correct way to write $N$ is $\{0\} \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z$. And what is the second question?

Comment: @azif00, does it require that in $G$, $a_0≠0$?

Comment: In $G$, $a_0$ is any integer.

Comment: Hence, @azif00, is $N \trianglelefteq G$?

Comment: Yes, $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ (we don’t talk about normality in abelian groups theory). Perhaps, $\trianglelefteq$ has a different meaning here? I don’t know the context.

Comment: For the same reason, Joshua, that ${\bf R}^2$ is not a subset of ${\bf R}^3$. An element of the one is not an element of the other.